# A compiler error while using ternary operator

Tags: typescript

I am using typescript 0.9.0.1 in Visual Studio 2012.
At a time I use ternary operator in my code, compiler throws an error : *Type of conditional expression cannot be determined. Best common type could not be found between `void` and `boolean`.*

The code is :

```
export class event
{
    public static add (elem: HTMLElement, ev: string, fn: (ev: Event) => void, thisObj?)
    {
        var callFn = function (ev: Event) { fn.call(thisObj || elem, ev); };

        elem.addEventListener ? elem.addEventListener(ev, callFn, false) : elem.attachEvent('on' + ev, callFn);
    }
}
```

I try to use if-else instead of ternary operator. Then the error doesn't occur.

The code is :

```
export class event
{
    public static add (elem: HTMLElement, ev: string, fn: (ev: Event) => void, thisObj?)
    {
        var callFn = function (ev: Event) { fn.call(thisObj || elem, ev); };

        if (elem.addEventListener)
        {
            elem.addEventListener(ev, callFn, false);
        }
        else
        {
            elem.attachEvent('on' + ev, callFn);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error sais it all. It means one of the cases results to `void` while the other will result to `boolean`. As there's no common type for these two types, you can't use them in a ternary operator. Although in your particular case, it *could* be allowed as you're not assigning the result to a variable.

The error makes more sense if you would assign it to a variable:

```
var someVar = condition ? aMethodWhichReturnsBoolean : aMethodWhichReturnsVoid;
```

It should be clear that the compiler cannot know which type `someVar` would be and furthermore that it can't find another type which would satisfy both `boolean` and `void`. Hence it will throw an error.

In your case expanding the ternary operator again to an if/else statement will solve the error, but (to be complete) in the example I have given you'd need to specify the type of `someVar` as `any`.

Comment: You are very helpful. My English is not so well that I can't understand the error message clearly. I have been not realized it that it could return a value of different types while using ternary operator.

Comment: From your question I couldn't tell you're English is bad :) My mistake and glad to have helped!